# What criteria does isValid( "telephone", PN ) use to validate phone numbers in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

In ColdFusion, `isValid()` with a type of "telephone" validates a US phone number. However, it's not just looking at the number of digits.

For example:

```
isValid( "telephone", "8002345678" )  // returns true
isValid( "telephone", "1111111111" )  // returns false
```

Besides the number of digits, what rules or regex does CF use to validate a phone number?

Comment: Same is true in Lucee (https://trycf.com/gist/88cadfd0e303774435ebc35e452cc1ad/lucee5?theme=monokai), so you could look in the Lucee repo on github to see how Lucee does it https://github.com/lucee/Lucee

Comment: **(Update)** I've always been leery of IsValid since the exact rules for things like phone numbers aren't defined anywhere AFAIK. Usually regexes for U.S. phone numbers validate the NXX-NPA-XXXX ([North American Numbering Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan)) pattern, which say the first digit of the area code and exchange shouldn't be 1 or 0 (and other rules). So "9119111111" would be considered valid. Sadly, whatever regex IsValid uses also returns true for an invalid number like "1119111111". Not very robust. IMO, you're better off looking elsewhere.

Comment: @Redtopia - that's a great suggestion. However, we're using CF11 & 2016 at the moment, so to be sure, I would want to find out what Adobe uses.

Comment: Agreed, @Ageax. I wouldn't rely on it on its own. We may use it as a first-pass validation, though. The NANP is a good guess. That may be the answer.

Comment: If data entry of the phone numbers is coming from a web interface, you could you Stripe's mobile phone JS library to pre-validate. https://github.com/stripe/jquery.mobilePhoneNumber We use this on our web forms and it has been especially helpful with international phone numbers.  (Just be sure to strip non-digits before performing server-side validation.)

Answer (score -2):

We can able to validate US number using isValid() function.

```
<cfoutput>#isValid("regex", "(123) 123-1234","^(\([0-9]{3}\) |[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$")#</cfoutput>

<!--- format (123)123-1234 --->
<cfoutput>#isValid("regex", "(123)123-1234","^(\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$")#</cfoutput>

<!--- format 123-123-1234 --->
<cfoutput>#isValid("regex", "123-123-1234","^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$")#</cfoutput>
```

Thanks,

Comment: There are additional rules for NANP than just validating the numeric portion consists of ten digits, such as optional country code, area code cannot start start with a 0 or 1, etc..

Comment: This is a useful alternative, but the original question is asking what is behind CF's `isValid("telephone")`.